# ArrayLists and sub-lists

Tags: java, arraylist, sublist

Hello im rather stuck on this part of my java programming work. I have done what i think is right for this question but im unsure if it is right as the next question asks to add 4 different strings into two different sub-lists (and thats where im getting stuk).

This is the first question:

Create a variable called balancedThings of type ArrayList of ArrayLists of Strings and add a method balancedInit() that instantiates the balancedThings variable by creating a new ArrayList > object and that also creates two new ArrayList  objects and adds these to the balancedThings list.

this is the second question:

Add a method balancedCreation() that adds the strings “sword” and “map” to the first of the two sub-lists, and the strings “shield” and “bottle” to the second sub-list.

This is my answer:

```
void balancedInit()
    {
        balancedThings = new ArrayList<>();

        balancedThings.add(0, "SubListOne");

        balancedThings.add(1, "SubListTwo");
    }
```

Can anyone explain if this is right for the question and where i should go next in order to add into sublists?

Comment: `creates two new ArrayList objects and adds these to the balancedThings list` What do you **think** `balancedThings.add(0, "SubListOne");` is doing?

Comment: Yes, while you're supposed to add `ArrayList` objects. So, obviously it's not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to build the solution from the bottom up. Before worrying about the list of lists, worry about the individual lists first.

So first, you just want a list of strings. You can do that like this:

```
private static ArrayList<String> firstSublist() {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("sword");
        list.add("map");

        return list;
}
```

*ArrayList* is your list, and the *String* in angle brackets tells you what type is going to be in the list. Then you add the actual strings. Do this for the other sublist too.

Then when you have a way to make your little lists, time to compose the big one:

```
private static void balancedCreation(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfLists) {
        listOfLists.add((firstSublist()));
        listOfLists.add((secondSublist()));
}
```

Here you have a list *of lists*. I know all the angle brackets can be confusing with something like `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`, but just remember to look at it a little at a time from the inside out.

So with the big list, you are just adding a thing--exactly like the sublists. As long as you take care of business at the simpler level, building up to the top level is no sweat.

In the end, *main* looks like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
        balancedCreation(listOfLists);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you want to add an ArrayList of Strings in an ArrayList :

```
public void balancedInit() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> balancedThings = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> subListOne = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> subListTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
    // add values to your Sub Lists then ...

    balancedThings.add(subListOne); //  this will be index 0 implicitly
    balancedThings.add(subListTwo); //  this will be index 1 implicitly
}
```

programmers prefer using polymorphism in Collections framework, like declaring the ArrayList as List, but this is not a good practice when it comes to Serialization

Answer (score 0):

initialize andinstantiate the "SublistOne" and "SubListTwo" in the way you initialized the BalancedThings.
that should create the sublist.

```
void balancedInit()
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> balancedThings = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> subLiostOne =  = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> subLiostTwo =  = new ArrayList<String>();

        subListOne.add(0,"sword");
        subListOne.add(1,"map");

        subListTwo.add(0,"shield");
        subListTwo.add(1,"bottle");

        balancedThings.add(0, subListOne);

        balancedThings.add(1, subListTwo);
    }
```

please mark the answer as helpful if it is helpful

Comment: Please stick to Java naming conventions, variables are in lower camel case.

Comment: Thanks Boris, I have been developing in non Java lately. Please consider my last line of the post